# c# application read image through proxy

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a program to create https image request.

My program was successfully to read the image.
Here is part of my code :

```
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(" Image URL ");
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0";
request.Accept = "image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5";
request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.5");
request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");

request.KeepAlive = true;

response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
}
response.Close();
```

Then I tried to send the image request through a fiddler remote proxy , it failed.
And throw the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream)
   at ..
```

Whats wrong with my code ?

Comment: Try activating gzip `HttpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression` in order to avoid passing a compressed stream to the image factory